# Proper way to unit test NestJS controller?

Tags: nestjs

I'm new to NestJS and would like to understand how I can unit test an endpoint with config dependencies and 3rd party library dependencies.

Code flow is along the lines of

Main -> Controller -> Service

Service uses config values from ConfigModule and passes these values to a third party library for authentication. The config values themselves are loaded in onModuleInit.

Please let me know if examples/code snippets are required. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

[This repository](https://github.com/jmcdo29/testing-nestjs) has a lot of examples on unit testing with NestJS.

In general, with the class your testing, you should mock out the dependencies being injected into it using a [custom provider](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers). Then you can have complete control over what values are being returned from the dependencies